# Cannot read currentTimeMillis in BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to measure how long each Bluetooth discovery process takes place. I assign `currentTimeMillis` to startTime and stopTime. When I put the `BroadcastReceiver` class as inner class, I can read both variables, but when I make it as an outer class, I cannot read startTime. Here is my code,

```
private long startTime;
private long stopTime;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String strIntent = intent.getAction();
    if (strIntent.equalsIgnoreCase(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED)) {
        handleDiscStarted();
    } else if (strIntent.equalsIgnoreCase(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED)) {
        handleDiscFinished();
    }
}

private void handleDiscStarted() {
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Log.d(tag, "\nDiscovery started " + startTime);
}

private void handleDiscFinished() {
    stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    Log.d(tag, "\nDiscovery finished " + stopTime + ", takes " + (stopTime-startTime) + " ms");
    // startTime = 0 here...
    Log.d(tag, "\nstopTime=" + stopTime + ", startTime=" + startTime);
}
```

Any idea why the different behaviors occur? How can I read startTime in the second case? Thanks!

Comment: How do you signal when the discovery finishes? Looks to me the second statement is unreachable unless you dont signal for finished discovery and start the broadcaster again, which will cause loosing the starttime. This is how I understand.

Comment: I use onClick to start and stop the discovery. It's the same code for either inner or outer class. Ok, what if I start the discovery and just let it finished? I should be able to read the startTime value, right? which is not the case here..

Comment: What I mean by unreachable is, I bet you start the broadcaster reciever at some point where you have started the discovery, which means only the first `if` is envoked, it cant go to the `else`, the broadcaster only  recieves that discovery has started.

Comment: Ow, thats another thing. Then the startTime is again intialised when you make call to the outer class. Try it like this. Start the counting from the onClick() send the time in the intent data to the broadcaster, and when you finish just substract with the final time. It's just another way around to avoid loosing of start time.

Comment: when u make that an outer class where will you put those 2 methods...?

Comment: I've edited my answer for the second part of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this. Start the counting from the `onClick()` send the initial time in the `intent` data to the `BroadcastReciever`, and when you finish the discovery just substract with the final time you get in the `BroadcastReciever`. It's just another way around to avoid loosing of start time. If you are calling start and stop of discovery from the same button make sure the logic works, and `do not send the initial time twice`.

Comment: Do I get it right? In outer class, when I explicitly tell the discovery process to stop, another receiver object is created and startTime is initialized again, while in inner class, the object is created only once, so the startTime is preserved.

Comment: Quite close. You initialize starTime in the inner class where you have the onClick method. (You said you are startign the broadcast rieceiver from that onclick method) Put the value of startTime in the intent as extra data. When you stop extract it in the outer class in the BroadcastReciever and get the final result. Hope this makes sense to you. P.S: Your comment above is reasonable to me, you can try it that way. And you dont need to handle the start of the discovery in the BroadcastReciever if you do these ways.

Comment: Yes, I understand the steps you told me to try. My comment is just a reasoning as to why I can read the startTime in inner class and not in outer class. Thanks, I think I got it now!

Answer (score 2):

Taken from the [Receiver Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle):

> A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call
>   to onReceive(Context, Intent).

Therefore the start time you initially recorded will not exist when you calculate the end time.

If you want to keep track of this start time appropriately, I suggest keeping track of it in persistent storage, in this case `SharedPreferences`.